# Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. How to return it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, render

From what I've been reading, the error is generated by trying to print '{menu.props.options[0]}'. I understand that I can't return it like this since I have to wrap it in an object or array.

The code in question is:

```
return (
  <Select
    labelInValue
    filterOption={ false }
    showArrow
    suffixIcon={ <SearchOutlined /> }
    onSearch={ debounceFetcher }
    notFoundContent={ fetching ? <Spin size="small" /> : null }
    { ...props }
    className="search-repeated-words"
    dropdownRender={menu => (
      <div>
        {menu.props.options[0]}
        <div style={{ padding: "0 12px", height: 30, lineHeight: "30px", color: "#46C4C1" }} >
           Sugerencias
        </div>
        <Divider style={{ margin: 5 }} />
        {menu}
      </div>
    )}
  >
  {
    options.map((option, index) => (
        <Select.Option key={index} value={option.text}>
          <span>{option.text}</span>
        </Select.Option>
      )
    )
  }
</Select>
```

What solution can I implement?

---

menu.props.options[0] = object :
[image]

The error is generated when I want to print or display {menu.props.options[0]} on the screen. How could I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess `{menu.props.options[0]}` is an object. You should only display the relevant property of this object, with a primitive type (a string, for example) such as `menu.props?.options?.[0]?.label`

Comment: With this it doesn't give me a long error but it doesn't show me what I want either. The idea of all this is to show the first result of the select (what I am typing in real time) first, then a <div> Suggestions </div> then a <Divider /> and then all the other options

Comment: Excellent! Printing it as 'menu.props?.options?.[0]?.value' showed me the text I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the error is generated by trying to render

```
{menu.props.options[0]}
```

then it means that menu.props.option[0] is an Object type and you should either render it like

```
<div>{menu.props.options[0].title} {menu.props.options[0].description}</div>
```

(depending on what properties does the object consist of)

or if you for some reason want to render an object as is:

```
<div>{ JSON.stringify(menu.props.options[0]) }</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is an object type! Take a look at the image attached to the post.

The menu.props.options[0].value thing didn't work for me --> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

The JSON.stringify thing didn't work for me. -> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
     --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
     | property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'
     --- property 'Provider' closes the circle

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function (or another component) which can render the `option` data. Below I've created one labeled `OptionCell` which is used to both render the first element as well as the the entire option array:

```js
const OptionCell = (option) => (
  <Select.Option key={index} value={option.text}>
    <span>{option.text}</span>
  </Select.Option>
)

return (
  <Select
    labelInValue
    filterOption={ false }
    showArrow
    suffixIcon={ <SearchOutlined /> }
    onSearch={ debounceFetcher }
    notFoundContent={ fetching ? <Spin size="small" /> : null }
    { ...props }
    className="search-repeated-words"
    dropdownRender={menu => (
      <div>
        {<OptionCell options={menu.props.options[0]} />)
        <div style={{ padding: "0 12px", height: 30, lineHeight: "30px", color: "#46C4C1" }} >
           Sugerencias
        </div>
        <Divider style={{ margin: 5 }} />
        {menu}
      </div>
    )}
  >
  {
    options.map((option, index) => (
      <OptionCell options={options} key={index} />
    )
  }
  </Select>
)
```

Comment: Does not recognize the 'index' in the helper function. In the post I attached an image of the object that returns me.